# Displaying a value real time on Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to build a web app which displays random numbers changing by real time without the need of refreshing the page.

Here is my code that works when I refresh but not real-time:

```
from flask import *
import random
# Init the server
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

# Send HTML!
@app.route('/')
def root():
    i=0
    while i < 10:
        n=random.randint(0,9)
        return str(n)
        i += 1

# Actually Start the App
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """ Run the app. """
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8000', debug=True)
```

What code should I add to this so It will show it changing real-time?

Comment: As soon as you call`return`, the method will end. For page updates with no refresh, you will need an AJAX process where javascript calls the server in the background and updates the page. You can also check out push notifications but that may be more complicated.

Comment: This would be much more easily accomplished with client-side JavaScript than anything on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Because the page isn't reloading, you need to do this with JavaScript, which is on the client side. Because this is random numbers, you probably don't need to make an AJAX call, which is where the client and server communicate with each other without any page reloads. There is a JavaScript library called `Math` (docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)) which has a `Random` function. You could do something like this:

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

This should     return a random integer between min and max, including min but excluding max.